# Are Portals of Power cross-platform compatible?

Tags: skylanders, skylanders-giants, skylanders-swap-force

Can I use a portal from one platform on another platform? Is there a difference between the 1st/2nd generation portals (Spyro's Adventure/Giants) and the 3rd generation one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I know so far, based on my own experience and [other online resources](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/625204-skylanders-spyros-adventure/answers?qid=304704):

**First/Second generation portals - Spyro's Adventure (green base)/Giants (orange base)**

- **X360/PC portals (wired)** - Works on their respective platforms.
- **PS3/Wii wireless portals** - Interchangeable, work on both platforms as well as PC.
- **3DS portal** - Works on 3DS using IR and on every other platform beside X360 when connected with a mini-USB cable. Limited due to its size so might not be optimal.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Wii U wired giants USB portal with the Wii.

Comment: hello, and welcome to Arqade. We're a QA site, not a forum, so I've removed the additional question from your answer. If you have a question of your own, please use the ASK QUESTION button in the top right.